# What is the thread model of vertx kafka client

Tags: apache-kafka, threadpool, vert.x

```
 consumer.handler(record->{

    });
```

I use this method to handle business logic,but I found that it is always handled by a thread eventloop.How do I use a thread pool to process data,but not just a eventloop thread

Comment: Some more context would be appreciated. How do you start the consumer, exactly? 
In general, Kafka client will reuse context it runs on. My guess is that you're running this in a regular verticle, not a worker verticle, and hence it uses the event loop instead of worker thread pool.

Comment: Did you get this answer? we are deploying this verticle with the deployment options set as worker (DeploymentOptions workerDeployOpts = new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true)); any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a separate Worker verticle and create the consumer as part of start method of that verticle. Then all messages will be processed using the Worker thread pool.